# Error with class objects methods and proprities

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jmetalpy

I need to create a class schedule that minimizes overcrowding and misalignment. I'm using jmetalpy and jupyternotebook.

I'm creating a class problem so that I can run the NSGAII model with my problem.

However, when I run the code this error appears :

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class TimetablingProblem with abstract methods name, number_of_constraints, number_of_objectives
```

This is my code:

```
class TimetablingProblem(FloatProblem):
    
    def __init__(self, horarioblank, caracteristicas_salas):
        
        super().__init__()

        self.horarioblank = horarioblank
        self.caracteristicas_salas = caracteristicas_salas

        self.number_of_variables = len(horarioblank)  # Number of shifts
        self.number_of_objectives = 2  # Overcrowding rate and inadequacy rate
        self.number_of_constraints = 0

        self.lower_bound = np.zeros(self.number_of_variables)
        self.upper_bound = np.full(self.number_of_variables, len(caracteristicas_salas) - 1)

    def evaluate(self, solution: FloatSolution) -> None:
        alocacoes_salas = solution.variables

        sobrelotacao = 0
        inadequacao = 0

        for i, turno in enumerate(self.horarioblank):
            sala_alocada = self.caracteristicas_salas.iloc[int(alocacoes_salas[i])]
            inscritos = turno['Inscritos no turno']

            if inscritos > sala_alocada['Capacidade_Normal']:
                sobrelotacao += inscritos - sala_alocada['Capacidade_Normal']

            if sala_alocada['combined'] not in turno['Características reais da sala']:
                inadequacao += 1

        solution.objectives[0] = sobrelotacao
        solution.objectives[1] = inadequacao

    def create_solution(self) -> FloatSolution:
        solution = FloatSolution(
            lower_bound=self.lower_bound,
            upper_bound=self.upper_bound,
            number_of_objectives=self.number_of_objectives,
            number_of_constraints=self.number_of_constraints
        )
        return solution

    def get_name(self) -> str:
        return "Timetabling Problem"
```

Any idea of what i'm missing here?

Comment: check if the `FloatProblem` class is an abstract class; If it is, try to implement all its methods

Comment: `FloatProblem` has abstract methods `number_of_constraints` and `number_of_objectives` that it does not implement itself. Inheriting classes are expected to implement them. You can look back at the help or source code for that class to see what to do next.